# How to learn Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to learn CakePHP framework and I dont have enough time to research it, so I need a book or any online tutorial which will enable me to learn it quickly. Please suggest any online tutorial or books, if any.

Comment: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-cakephp is a great place to find best online CakePHP tutorials. All the tutorials here are submitted and recommended (upvoted like SO) by the programming community.

Answer (score 7):

The cakePHP official manual is the answer http://book.cakephp.org/
Nowhere to go the official site manual and documentation is sufficient.

Comment: Nothing is better than this book.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think the best way to learn the framework is to go out and build something with it, and refer back to the book (mentioned in previous answers) when you come across a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Without a doubt, the best tutorial available online or elsewhere is the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog) from the online manual.

Beyond that, read the [official book](http://book.cakephp.org/). Read it well - a surprising number of people don't.

Also, the [API reference](http://api13.cakephp.org/) will improve the depth of your knowledge.

I've noticed recently that the 1.3 manual isn't as well written as the 1.2 manual, so be prepared for a bit of sideways reading.

Comment: I am working with v 1.3. And I found a good deal of helpful answers in the 1.2 manual which did not exist in the 1.3.