# Cakephp 3.x Static Pages with menu bar and image gallery

Tags: cakephp

Hi good day to everyone.. I got a simple project that needs to be done using cakephp 3 as its framework.. I was having a hard time to build some pages and link them into a menu bar or navigation bar.. I am new to cakephp but my client wants it to be built using this framework on latest release.. and it needs an image gallery.. how can I possibly do it? can somebody good in cakephp gives me a step by step procedure on this.. I'm just afraid I am not going to do this properly.. Please help me or give me some advice. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Your *client* wants *you* to do it? Guess for money? And you want somebody to do *your* work, guess for free? I doubt this is going to happen... SO is not a "request a tutorial" site or a free coding service.

Comment: Maybe you are right @burzum :) I respect your respond. But I want you to know that it is not my intention to make somebody do my work.. I'm just asking for a guide or maybe there will be someone out there who will tell me how to do it properly, who are more experienced with this framework.. just a simple heads-up for a beginner.. thanks anyway for letting me know I asked the wrong question.. or probably the wrong way..

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials available on how to implement a gallery. You can get the idea and database schema from them. For CakePHP, just follow the MVC pattern, which you can learn by doing the blog tutorial (book.cakephp.org). Your question is definitely "too broad" to be answered here because it would require somebody to write a complete tutorial exclusive for you. Alternatively look at existing open source gallery plugins for CakePHP. But be aware that probably most of them are not very well done.

Comment: Thanks brother :) sometimes a simple consultation would solve a problem. Next time I will make sure I will ask an specific question.. It's just I'm a newbie to SO. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CakePHP 3.x** is not stable yet, latest stable version is **2.6.0**. I think you should go with stable version.

**learning CakePHP**

[CakePHP official website](http://cakephp.org/) gives very good documentation, you can easily follow and start coding.

you can start [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html#getting-started). And some links may help you:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-cakephp--net-1218

[How to learn Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960386/how-to-learn-cakephp)

Comment: Sorry, I can't vote this answer up.. and thank you for this.. I still want to learn the 3.0 version though.. seems more interesting.. thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm so happy to see someone like who is always willing to help :)
and by the way.. can you tell me a link to how to make a menu for pages in cakephp.. a navigation bar or something like that.. and image gallery as well.. I tried to search it in google but no luck. thanks in advance..